# Unique attribute with scope of another attribute in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to create an attribute on a Sequelize model that only enforces uniqueness within the scope of another attribute?

For example, let's say `foo` has to be unique:

```
Thing.create({ foo: 1, bar: 1 });
Thing.create({ foo: 1, bar: 1 }); // Uniqueness violation!
```

But I want the following to be allowed:

```
Thing.create({ foo: 1, bar: 1 });
Thing.create({ foo: 1, bar: 2 }); // Allowed since bar is a different value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a `compositeIndex`.

When defining the model, the value you pass to the `unique` validation can be a string. If the string you provide matches another unique validation value on another attribute, those attributes will create a composite index that will enforce uniqueness to those combination of values.

From the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models/#model-validations):

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {

  someUnique: {type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true},
  uniqueOne: { type: Sequelize.STRING,  unique: 'uniqueCombo'},
  uniqueTwo: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, unique: 'uniqueCombo'}

});
```